# Customfield columns in Jira tables using Jira Linked Service with Azure Data Factory

Tags: jira, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Good Day

I am looking for the tables (using the Jira connector for Azure data factory) that carries the customfields data for Jira.

I extracted the following tables, but are still unable to find a specific custom field, in my case thhe custom fields i am looking for : custom field 12680 and 12900

I cannot find these fields mentioned above in the following tables

"Extra"."Agile_Board_Backlog_Issues"

"Extra"."Agile_Board_Epic_Issue"

"Extra"."Agile_Board_Issue"

"Extra"."Agile_Board_Sprint_Issue"

"Extra"."Api_Issue"

Does anyone know of other tables i can potentially look at to get customfields data?

Regards

Rayno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is more on the lines as to "How Jira stores the custom fields " . I am not not sure if you have seen [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/which-database-table-holds-custom-fields-information/qaq-p/230385) post . HTM

Comment: Thanks Himanshu i will have a look at that post.